# IE7 & IE8 rendering problem - text moving

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, rendering

We just rolled out a new application on our site, www.net54baseball.com.  Using Javascript, we are allowing users to Show or Hide the app.  When the user clicks Show, the app opens and exposes a list of hyperlinks.  It functions perfectly in Firefox and Chrome.  However, in IE7 & IE8, the hyperlinked text appears properly for a split second, then drops down about an inch.  When the user's mouse passes over each link, it moves back up to its correct spot.  Firefox/Chrome users love the app, but this is extremely frustrating for IE users.

The app is on this page:  [www.net54baseball.com](http://www.net54baseball.com)

Why does the text drop down after opening?  How can I prevent this behavior in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Scott Greenwald

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but here's a trick that's worked for me in the past when IE has "painting" issues.  After you "Show" the element, set the element style to "position: relative;".  This should force IE to repaint the element and position it back to where it needs to be.  If that doesn't work, try adding a setTimeout after you show the element and then change the style to "position: relative;" inside the setTimeout callback.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: very nice, I just added * {position:relative;} and it fixed the rendering error

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well. The text was moving to the bottom of the screen. It happened in IE8 but was working fine in Firefox.